# How to solve MAUI Shell.SearchHandler crashes when running on IOS environment?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, visual-studio, maui

In my Project I have setup a Shell.SearchHandler, it works perfectly when I run on Android Emulator but crashes when I trying to type something in the search bar when I running on IOS Emulator.
It keeps pointing system null reference and crash immediately. Any solution for this?

**StudentModel.cs**

```
    public class StudentModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

**StudentListViewModel.cs**

```
    public class StudentListViewModel
    {
        public static List<StudentModel> Students { get; private set; } = new List<StudentModel>();

        public StudentListViewModel()
        {
            Students.Add(new StudentModel
            {
                Name = "asd",
                Email = "asd@123.com",
            });
            Students.Add(new StudentModel
            {
                Name = "qwe",
                Email = "qwe@123.com",
            });
            Students.Add(new StudentModel
            {
                Name = "ert",
                Email = "rty@123.com",
            });
        }
    }
```

**StudentListView.Xaml**

```
    <Shell.SearchHandler>
        <searchHandlers:StudentSearchHandler
            DisplayMemberName="Name"
            Students="{x:Static vm:StudentListViewModel.Students}">


        </searchHandlers:StudentSearchHandler>

    </Shell.SearchHandler>
```

**StudentSearchHandler.cs**

```
    public class StudentSearchHandler : SearchHandler
    {
        public IList<StudentModel> Students { get; set; }
        protected override void OnQueryChanged(string oldValue, string newValue)
        {
            base.OnQueryChanged(oldValue, newValue);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newValue))
            {
                ItemsSource = null;
            }
            else
            {
                ItemsSource = Students.Where(student => student.Name.ToLower().Contains(newValue.ToLower())).ToList();
            }
        }

        protected override async void OnItemSelected(object item)
        {
            base.OnItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
```

How to solve this error? Thanks.
I tried to set a breakpoint to test on different emulators, Android emulator will execute
`protected override void OnQueryChanged(string oldValue, string newValue){}`
method, but when running on an IOS emulator will not go into this method.

Comment: What does the stack trace show as the cause of the crash?  It should identify a specific line number.  Or you could add some exception handling to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a known issue on .NET Maui. You could follow this issue [[iOS] Shell.SearchHandler crashes the app](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7553) .

Additionally, you might use **SearchBar** as an alternative. For more info, you could refer to [.NET Maui SearchBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/searchbar?view=net-maui-7.0).